# Add registry with cmd script

Tags: windows-10, batch, cmd.exe

I want to set compatibility mode via cmd and therefore i created a batch-script (see code) which adds a registry to the .exe-file in the current direcotry.
The only problem is, when I use `"%CD%\Launcher.exe"` the registry-name (path) is set wrong -> `C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Games\NEWFOL~1\Launcher.exe`

But when I enter the full path to the script, the registry name is correct. Why is that so and how do you fix that?

This is my script:

```
@echo off

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
    IF "%PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE%" EQU "amd64" (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\SysWOW64\config\system"
) ELSE (
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"
)

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )

:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    set params= %*
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/c ""%~s0"" %params:"=""%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"

    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B

:gotAdmin
    pushd "%CD%"
    CD /D "%~dp0"
:--------------------------------------      
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v "%CD%\Launcher.exe" /t REG_SZ /d "WIN98 256COLOR 640X480" /f
exit
```

Comment: Does `%CD%` contain spaces?

Comment: Yes, it does. May this be the problem ?

Comment: It may be. I'm not able to test for you though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add escape **\"quotes\"**:

[image]

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v \""%CD%\Launcher.exe"\" /t REG_SZ /d \"WIN98 256COLOR 640X480\" /f
```

Or, only in your path, because I'm not sure if `"WIN98 256COLOR 640X480"` will need escaping to set these parameters...

[image]

```
<con: REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v \""%CD%\Launcher.exe"\" /t REG_SZ /d "WIN98 256COLOR 640X480" /f
```